# Clicking an image to check the checkbox?

Tags: android, imageview

I just started to develop to android, please help.

I cant figure out what i am missing..
The checkbox checking works, I want also to check by tapping on the image.

this part works well:

```
        holder.checkbox.setId(position);
        holder.imageview.setId(position);
        holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {


            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                //ImageView cb1 = (ImageView) v;

                int id = cb.getId();


                if (thumbnailsselection[id])
                {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }

            //    ImageView im = (ImageView) v;

            }
        });
   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

here is the problem:

```
 holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {


            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v;
                int id = v.getId();

                if (thumbnailsselection[id])
                {
                    cb.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else
                {
                    cb.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }


            }});
```

Logcat:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView cannot be cast to android.widget.CheckBox
```

thanks.

Comment: First of all, IDs are unique, dont give the same ID to your imageview and checkbox

Comment: show your Full code of Activity

Comment: I think this happens because you are casting "v" from the onClick(View v) as a checkbox, but it is the ImageView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a common click listener,

```
View.OnClickListener clickListener = new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            int id = holder.checkbox.getId();

            if (thumbnailsselection[id])
            {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
            } else
            {
                holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
            }
        }
    };
```

Then set this listener to both imageview and checkbox like so,

```
holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(clickListener);
```

Comment: i am getting an error that variable holder is accessed from within inner class, needs to declared final

Comment: You could declare your holder globally and reinitialize it as needed.

Comment: what is the easiest way to do that? sorry for the questions and thank you for your help!

Comment: Your holder is declared inside the method that has the clickListener. Try declaring the holder outside the method.

Answer (score 0):

```
holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()public void onClick(View v){
  public void onClick(View v){
     CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v; // In here v is the ImageView not CheckBox so you will get java.lang.ClassCastException
```

And in your case, you can use

```
holder.imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){

                int id = holder.checkbox.getId();
                if (thumbnailsselection[id]){
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = false;
                } else {
                    holder.checkbox.setChecked(true);
                    thumbnailsselection[id] = true;
                }
            }
});
```

Comment: You are again trying to cast Imageview to checkbox

Comment: yes, but if I use ImageView i cant use the setChecked(false or true) part.

Comment: @Janos try Tony solution, it more reusable than my solution